# rails update attributes based on true or false statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read and tried everything that few people on Stackflow have suggested here without luck. So far I've got;

```
def save_with_payment
  if Subscription.where(:subscription_plan => "Yearly")
    update_attributes(expiry_date: Date.today.next_year)
  else
    update_attributes(expiry_date: Date.today.next_month)
  end
end
```

Somehow, it keeps setting the expiry_date to next year, even if :subscription_plan => "monthly".

Comment: Explain me the logic of your application. Now it is saying: 
If there are any Yearly subscriptions set expiry_date equal next_year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscription.where returns empty array if there are no "Yearly" subscriptions.

```
if [] #returns true
```

So your first condition will always be true. Use `exists?` instead

```
def save_with_payment
  if Subscription.exists?(:subscription_plan => "Yearly")
    update_attributes(expiry_date: Date.today.next_year)
  else
    update_attributes(expiry_date: Date.today.next_month)
  end
end
```

Comment: I might be wrong but shouldn't the OP be checking `subscription.subscription_plan == 'Yearly'` instead of `Subscription.where(:subscription_plan => 'Yearly')`? as this is an instance method.

Comment: vee doing subscription.subscription_plan == 'yearly' I get subscription_plan not defined for some strange reason. I might be wrong understanding this.

Comment: Thanks Vimsha, .exists? was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This arrangement is totally incorrect.

`Subscription.where(:subscription_plan => "Yearly")` will be true in most of the times because it's for **whole** Subscription model's data. If one of the record is `Yearly`, it's true.

Instead of querying whole model, do it on the user's own data.

Suppose User has one subscription, then

```
def save_with_payment
  subscription.yearly? ? extend_one_year : extend_one_month
end

def extend_one_year
  update_attributes(expiry_date: Date.today.next_year)
end

# def extend_one_year
```

Or better yet, such extending logic should belongs to Subscription but not User. Move it there. And also "Tell, don't ask"

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def next_extend_date
    next_date = subscription_plan.yearly? ? 'next_year' : 'next_month'
    Date.today.send next_date
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription

  def save_with_payment
    extend_to subscription.next_extend_date
  end

  # But I'm not sure if such logic still need to be in Subscrption.
  def extend_to(date)
    update_attribute expiry_date: date
  end
end
```

Comment: Vote this one up as I also think this is what OP should be doing!

Comment: @vee, thanks for the encouragement and nice to have same opinion with you!

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for the tips, I'm not trying to extend the subscription, but rather set appropriate expiry_date based on what a user selects. So I know my question was dirty coded, but I was trying to set different attribute based on the logic of what the column :subscription_plan has, yearly or monthly. If that makes better sense.

Comment: @user2419316, I think your logic is wrong. You set the expiry date according to whether there is a yearly record in whole table but not the users input. Imagine I subscribe Dropbox for a month, But Dropbox set my expiry date as next year just because you have a yearly plan!